# System.ArgumentException: 'Parâmetro inválido.'

Tags: c#, winforms

Criei um botão com `button24_Click_1` para tirar printscreen do Form1:

```
private void button24_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var frm = new Form1();
    using (var bmp = new Bitmap(frm.Width, frm.Height))
    {
        frm.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
        //bmp.Save(@"C:\Users\Matheus Miranda\Desktop\TESTE\screen.png");
    }
}
```

Segue o problema:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue erro do QuickWacth:

> **Message:**  "Parâmetro inválido."
>
> **ParamName:**    null
>
> **StackTrace:**      em System.Drawing.Image.get_RawFormat()
>      em System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height)
>      em System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, Rectangle rect)
>      em System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
>      em System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
>      em System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
>      em System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>      em System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>      em System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>      em System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Com código `bmp.Save();` funciona perfeitamente, só não consigo adicionar a foto direto para `picturebox1`. O que eu fiz de errado e como corrigir ?

Comment: Precisaria ver mais detalhes, nem sei onde o erro está ocorrendo. É possível que o `Bitmap` não esteja gerando um objeto. De qualquer forma este código deve dar erro, porque cria o objeto com `using`, o guarda em uma propriedade de outro objeto e termina a execução liberando o objeto, quando for acessar esta propriedade o objeto não existe mais.

Comment: @Maniero veja a resposta :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi problema, graça ao comentário do @**Manieiro**.

```
var frm = new Form1();
Bitmap pic = new Bitmap(frm.Width, frm.Height);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
rect = frm.ClientRectangle;
frm.DrawToBitmap(pic, rect);
pictureBox1.Image = pic;
```